# Drop down menu breaking footer

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, footer

I have an html file with really big drop down menus and a small page. When I'm just using the page and not touching the menu, the footer is at the bottom and there's no problem. When I use the drop down menu, the footer stays at the same place as before and there is a huge white space under it. I don't want it fixed (it's not for all pages so it will be ugly) but I want it to stay at the bottom always even if I open the drop downmenu and scroll. How can I do that? Here is the footer's css if that helps.

```
footer {
    margin-top: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgb(200,200,200);
    padding: 1%;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Provide the complete code

Answer (score 0):

As footer should be in bottom, so it should not have `margin-top` property instead it should have `bottom:0`.

Also, dropdown should have `max-height` css property, it should not be too long.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it's not helping me :/. The margin-top property is there for other reasons, as I said I don't have a problem with the bottom, only when I use the drop down menus. I don't want to make them shorter, that's why I asked how can I make the footer always at the bottom. Anyways, thank you for the time. :)

Comment: but that's the actual behaviour that if you have given `margin-top` to an element, it will be fixed to that margin and then you are trying to load drop down which is very big, as your footer is fixed by some margin so its position will not change. you have to use `bottom` property if you want something at the bottom of the page. or else provide your complete code